# Include local Files in Intranet Website

Tags: php, ldap

Before I try to explain it extensive, here is an illustration:

[image]

It´s not possible to include/embed local files in websites - i know.
But the Website is hosted on an Intranet Server.
And the Website "knows" me from the Active Directory (LDAP Login).
That works perfect.

My Question:
Is it possible to include a file (like "file.pdf") from a network drive in this Intranet Website??

Comment: "include" in PHP means something very specific (which does not apply to PDF files). You may need to further elaborate what you mean or rephrase.

Comment: mounting "//drive-xy" permanently seems to solve the problem. now the "website" can read local windows files from "windows network drive"

mount -t cifs -o user=winusername,password=password1 //drive-xy/data /media/intranet

don´t forget to edit fstab for permamently mounting